# Types of solutions of second order partial differential equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

We usually study types of solutions of first order partial differential equation with two independent variables: Complete solution, General solution, Particular solution, Singular solution. Over there we say that complete solutions involve arbitrary constants and number of arbitrary constants is equal to the number of independent variables (equal to two).

How shall we classify the solutions in case of:

1. first order partial differential equation with three independent variables
2. second order partial differential equation